# How do I fix this Attribute error in Python with Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

I'm currently trying to make a discord bot that runs python code. I have almost completed it, but I am met with an Attribute error on line 19

The exact error is: Attribute error: 'str' has no attribute 'exec'

````
import discord

def run_code_func(String_to_run):
  String_to_run.replace("`", "")
  String_to_run.lstrip("python")
  (String_to_run.rstrip("`"))
  String_to_run.exec()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("```python"):
    run_code = message.content
    run_code_func(run_code)
    


    


client.run("Secret")
````

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: I just updated the post, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `str.exec`, if you want to execute a string as code use `exec(String_to_run)`